# JBoss Envers ManyToOne Auditing

Tags: java, jboss, audit, many-to-one

Hypothetical scenario: I have two models: `Author` and `Book`. The `Book` model has a many-to-one relationship for `Author`.

Let's say that I only want to audit changes to `Book`. I annotate the class with `@Audited`, but get an error complaining that the `getAuthor()` property of `Book` can not be audited since `Author` is not audited.

Why is this? I want to audit if the author of the book changes, but I don't care if the authors nickname changes. It doesn't make sense for to have an `author_aud` table in my database, but apparently this is not possible unless I go ahead and audit the `Author` model OR specifically annotate the `getAuthor()` property with an `@Audited(...)` with a property to ignore the relationship. However, if I do this I will no longer be able to audit the book/author relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably not be able to audit the book and it's author relationship if the author is not audited.
Maybe you should change the way the relation is mapped : it's strange to have a book "own" it's author : I would have done an unidirectionnal manyToOne relationship from author to its books. With this conception, you will be able to audit the books without auditing the authors.

Comment: With the mapping you describe, if I have a list of books, will I be able to find the author via some "getAuthor"?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to get the author of the book if you have a unidirectional relation as suggested by @Romain Instead of seeing it as book "own" its author, I see it as book "has" an author. So if that is the case, Author will also be audited :-(

Answer (score 4):

Add this mapping to the ManyToOne relation.

@Audited( targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED )